# "a hundred of applications" vs. "a hundred applications."

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which of these sentences are correct:

> This job position nearly had a hundred of applications.

> This job position nearly had a hundred applications.

Should *of* be there? Why or why not?

Comment: "Hundred" is no different than any other number.  You would say, "The position had four applications" (not "four of applications").  Hundred follows the same rule. Also, "job position" is not idiomatic. Use either "job" or "position", but not both together.

Comment: might be useful: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hundred#Numeral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get mixed up between

> one/a hundred applications

and

> hundred***s*** ***of*** applications (200 or more)

Only if "hundred" is in the plural can it take the preposition "of".

However, as [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hundred) shows, you may come across such uses with the singular:

> One hundred (of the children) have already been placed with foster families.

> There were just a hundred of them there.